# VBA Filter and loop regression

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a regression multiple times and copying certain outputs (Intercept & Beta) into a new worksheet.
I am by no means a VBA programmer, this is the code I have come up with.

Basically, I have a field (field 6 in the below code). I need to run a regression on each of the filtered values in field 6 (which is a year/Quarter concatenation).

Any help would be great!

```
Sub RunRegression() ' ' RunRegression Macro '

'Add for loop to run through different filters
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AW$34712").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="20044"
     Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$AQ$1:$AQ$30274" _
        ), ActiveSheet.Range("$AF$1:$AF$30274"), False, True, , "Output", False _
        , False, False, False, , False
    Range("B17:B18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Sheets("Output").Delete
         End Sub
```

Comment: do you mean you have to call `ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress` for every single filtered cell?

Comment: More like, I have a dataset with quarters/years. and I want to run a regression for every quarter/year. I have 44000 rows and 44 different quarter/year combination.

Comment: then have your `Regress` Function loop through filtered cells only. You may want to post its code